# Explanation of a simple integral example

Tags: integration

I am trying to understand a solved integral example that use the substitution method, however, my problem is that I don't understand, how occurred in front of the integral $\frac{1}{2}$

Where it comes from?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Since $dt=2\ dx$ then $dx=\dfrac12\ dt$.